# Which NoSql for sensor data and reporting?

Tags: nosql, key-value-store, nosql-aggregation

I have problem deciding on which NoSql architecture stick to. Our business use case is that we have a lot of telemetry data coming from the assets. Which we need to regularly report based on.
We have a traditional web app halfway through development. We structured for front end apps to be consume from Rest based services so migrating to a NoSQL implementation is not a big deal. 
We have various reporting requirements and most of our reports are based on some basic queries. What worries me while moving to a NoSql Db is how do I create those nice easy queries where SQL server does most of the heavy lifting?
For my business case where I am not not doing lot of key value look ups which is noSQL implementation is a good choice?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by switch to a NoSQL database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB might be the solution you want depending on your specific [use cases](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Use+Cases) and requirements. They have a nice [SQL to Mongo mapping chart](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/SQL+to+Mongo+Mapping+Chart) that helps bridge the gap between SQL and NoSQL based solutions.  It sounds like Mongo might be what you are looking for.  It deals well in situations requiring near real-time analytics with regular updates.

Answer (score 0):

On-line service: 
there is a key value couch database at meeiot.org I am sharing trough it every 30 seconds 2 water processing unit tanks from 2 different locations controlled by UDOO running Linux. They have PWM/GPIO and 8 x Bmp080 TH sensors plus some analogue thermistors. In total over 30 data points.
I watch them and control them with 2 keys (in/out) @ meeIOT, and a simple cron bash which act as user input for the whole system